# NGINX: subfolder to subdomain redirection doesn't work

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

yesterday i switched my sites to a new server. now i have a problem, because one domain i now run as a subdomain, was previously accessed as a subfolder and a few sites, which I have no access to, are still using that domain.com/subfolder/?some=parameters

so, long story short:
i need to update my nginx config file, to redirect my users from domain.com/subfolder/?some=parameters to subfolder.domain.com/?some=parameters

i searched for a solution for that problem yesterday, but couldn't fix the problem.

currently i have this in my conf file:

```
location /subfolder/ {
    rewrite ^/subfolder(/.*)$ http://subfolder.domain.com$1 permanent;
}
```

which obviously redirects all requests from domain.com/subfolder/?some=parameters to subfolder.domain.com/?some=parameters, but requests to domain.com/subfolder/styles.css aren't redirected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is due to a conflicting location directive for specific static file extensions in your nginx config. I was able to get your rule to work by making it use a regular expression which influences the priority.

```
location ~ /subfolder/.* {
    rewrite ^/subfolder(/.*)$ http://subfolder.domain.com$1 permanent;
}
```

See the details about the [location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) directive, especially the rules and examples there about precedence.